# Word Macros Problem: MsgBox function appears to lock all open windows of word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have some macros that run in Word. We are migrating to Office 2007.

Problem: the `MsgBox` function appears to lock all open windows of word. Any Ideas on how to get around that?

(It is a macro that walks a user through a bunch of prompts for information that they enter into user forms and or `MsgBox`es.) The error says:

> The command cannot be completed because a dialog box is open. Click OK then close all open dialog boxes to continue.

Is there any way to have each window of Word act independently of each other? The problem is that the information is frequently cut and pasted from other open Word documents, and this doesn't work as the `MsgBox` locks control of ALL windows of Word 2007.

The macros are pretty simple, but if you want to see the code, I will certainly post it. Basically, the old version of office let you go between windows, while 2007, that we are migrating to does not. I have run all the updates I could find. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

MsgBox, as far as I recall, is application modal. Perhaps you can create a small user form to use in place of MsgBox?